# Writing XML attribute in-line rather than with <value>...</value> tags

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Below is a sample of some XML that I am writing. This is valid XML, but in an attempt to cut down the file size I'd like to remove the  tags and simply write the value in-line with the attribute.

**What I currently have**

```
<custom-attributes>
  <custom-attribute attribute-id="isDropShip">
    <value>false</value>
  </custom-attribute>
  <custom-attribute attribute-id="restrictPayPal">
    <value>false</value>
  </custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>
```

**What I'd prefer to have**

```
<custom-attributes>
  <custom-attribute attribute-id="isDropShip">false</custom-attribute>
  <custom-attribute attribute-id="restrictPayPal">false</custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>
```

**List holding custom attributes and extending list add method**

```
 List<sharedTypeSiteSpecificCustomAttribute> custom = new List<sharedTypeSiteSpecificCustomAttribute>();
 custom.AddAttribute("isDropShip", dropship);
 custom.AddAttribute("restrictPayPal", subClass);
```

**Add method extension**

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void AddAttribute(this List<sharedTypeSiteSpecificCustomAttribute> list, string id, string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            return;
        }
        list.Add(new sharedTypeSiteSpecificCustomAttribute { attributeid = id, value = new[] { value } });
    }
}
```

**XSD sharedTypeSiteSpecificCustomAttribute code**

```
public partial class sharedTypeSiteSpecificCustomAttribute : sharedTypeCustomAttribute
{

    private string siteidField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("site-id")]
    public string siteid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.siteidField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.siteidField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**sharedTypeCustomAttribute code**

```
public partial class sharedTypeCustomAttribute
{

    private string[] valueField;

    private string[] textField;

    private string attributeidField;

    private string langField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("value")]
    public string[] value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string[] Text
    {
        get
        {
            return this.textField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.textField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("attribute-id")]
    public string attributeid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.attributeidField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.attributeidField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
    public string lang
    {
        get
        {
            return this.langField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.langField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. This is new to me and I'm just trying to learn the best practices and approaches.

Comment: already explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096797/should-i-use-elements-or-attributes-in-xml

Comment: @Y.S That answer seems great for explaining the advantages and disadvantages to each style, but that isn't my question. I am asking specifically how to remove the <value>...</value> tags and write the values in-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by implementing `IXmlSerializable` on class `sharedTypeSiteSpecificCustomAttribute`

```
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteAttributeString("attribute-id", attributeid);
        writer.WriteValue(value);
    }
```